# Open cart by external URL using cart ID

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have a script that adds items to a cart from an external source. The cart is created and products added and now I want to return a URL to the cart.

This URL should open the checkout cart and display the cart contents.

Here is the script so far but it opens to an empty cart

```
<?php

include '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$cartId = $_GET['id'];

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);

$quote->setIsActive(true)->save();

$Url= Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');

echo $Url;

?>
```

Comment: Is it just one product always? If so why don´t you just use this www.yourUrl/checkout/cart/add/product/PRODUCTID ?

Comment: No there are multiple products added to the cart in another php script. So once the cart is created and products added I need to open a new window from a url to view the checkout page

Comment: I need a way to open a previously populated cart using cart id / url

Answer (score 0):

Replace current quote:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote($quote);
```

But it will be better to merge custom quote items to current quote

```
$currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
var_dump($currentQuote->getData());

$items = $currentQuote->getAllItems();

var_dump('before: ' . count($items) . ' items');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getId());
}

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);

// add custom validation
$isAllowedToBeAdded = $quote->getId();

if ($isAllowedToBeAdded) {

    // Merge your quote to current quote
    $currentQuote->merge($quote)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->replaceQuote($currentQuote);
}

$items = $currentQuote->getAllItems();
var_dump('after: ' . count($items) . ' items');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getId());
}
var_dump($currentQuote->getData());
```

Comment: This is fine - the products are in the cart - now how to return a URL from your example that will open the checkout page ??            www.mySite.com/checkout.php/checkout/cart --- returns 404     www.mySite.com/index.php/checkout/cart - opens empty cart page